# How to show a notification if a word is present anywhere on an URL, even in pop-up

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Please excuse if this is a silly question. I was trying to create a chrome extension which will read the text in a web page and notify a user by any means if it is present at page anywhere even in pop up.

I have created extension but not getting how to write logic.

If any specific word is present then that should be flagged by any means. Those specific words can be maintained in a Google sheet and extension can use that as a reference to flag.

Comment: It's not clear how much you know about extensions and where you're stuck so I don't think we can help you unless you clarify these points. Generally you would start with a tutorial or the [official overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) and you'll see you need a `content script` to access web page contents. Inside of it you can use all the standard things for JavaScript/DOM.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, I have seen that description and prepared content script but I am not getting what script to write so that it reads. For example: I have a Google sheet where I have written some words in columns and when I visit suppose any website like facebook.com then the extension should read the content present on that website page and alert message should be show to visitor which says "this page contains Defined word in sheet or something like this any message we decide later."

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @wOxxOm, go through the official tutorial to get a good understanding of what you're trying to accomplish and how to use the content script.

And IMO, I would use Chrome.storage api [chrome storage api](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage), if they're saved to a variable, you can then access it locally, instead of you checking google sheets or some other external site, you're just checking the stored object.